# How fast can an object spin?

Tags: general-relativity, angular-momentum

Without any forces in space to stop it, assuming an object does not collide with anything or enters any kind of gravitational pull, how fast could the object spin. I mean the earth spins quite fast, but relatively not. As technically, an infinite force was to make it spin in the same direction faster and faster everyday, could it not be spinning much much much faster....like infinitely fast?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maximum rotational speed](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11762/)