# Is there a limit in angular speed in special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, angular-velocity

I was thinking in the following problem:

> Suppose I have a bar of lenght $l$. If I spin it with constant angular velocity $\omega$, according to the special theory of relativity, is there a limit to it's angular velocity?

I was thinking that maybe I should make the limit $ω_{\text{max}}=c/l$, but it doesn't make sense to me that the limit should depend in the bar's length. And even if this is right, what happens to the bar's shape? Does it remain straight?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate a long bar in space and get close to (or even beyond) the speed of light $c$](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2774/)