# Energy of a rotating disc in SR

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, speed-of-light, rotational-kinematics

[image]

I spent a long time trying to solve this however I still don't have an answer. The prof who gave me the question said that I should think of it like Newtonian mechanics and then solve it with relativity. I'm assuming that means $KE=I\omega^2/2$. I and omega depend on R, which changes due to length contraction. I tried 3 different thing and got 3 different answers. One of them was 0, the other 1/2mv^4 and infinity.

Comment: See [Rotate a long bar in space and get close to (or even beyond) the speed of light $c$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2774)

Comment: What is the energy if the mass of the disk is concentrated at the rim, so that $I=mR^2$? 
 ... Maybe you got the correct answer. Ask your prof to explain his solution.

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201492/25301